How to trigger a Power Automate Flow - while updating an Entity?
Platform - Power Automate(Flows)/Power Apps(Cloud Flows)
I want to trigger a flow everytime it was updated but the flow must not be triggered if one specific column(ex. 'address') is updated.

In other words, If 'address' is updated do not trigger the flow otherwise trigger the flow.

Please tell me how to achieve this in a feasible way??
The flow starts like below image. What can I do here?


The only way is to identify columns you want to run flow for and exclude the others like columns related to Address information.
Flow only run for the columns listed inside select columns field. Multiple  columns can be selected with comma. Use column logical name (found under advance options of column properties)

